# Different behaviour during converting a list of Strings to String array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

I was working on Collection framework in Java , where i encountered a strange problem . 
I made 2 lists of Strings  1 with the help of ArrayList while second was made using Arrays.asList(T ...).

After creation of these two list i tried to convert these lists into String arrays with the list.toArray() ,
as list.toArray() method call returns an object array , so i had to explicitly cast to String[] .

After casting some strange behaviour is happening as :

Case #1 : ( where list was created using ArrayList) , gives runtime exception as 
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Case 2 : (where list as created using Arrays.asList(T ... ) ) runs fine .

here is the code

```
String [] str = null ,str1 = null ;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a");
str = (String[]) list.toArray();  // Runtime Exception 
str1 = (String[]) list1.toArray(); // Runs Fine
```

Answer (score 7):

An [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is backed by an `Object[]`. A copy of that array is returned with `toArray()`.

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper
>   sequence (from first to last element).

It make no guarantees on the type of array returned. But we know this from the exception's message. If you want it to return a `String[]`, use the overloaded method provided for this reason.

```
 str = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

The cast becomes unnecessary.

The `List` implementation returned by [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) maintains a reference to the array (implicit or explicit) passed as its variable arity argument.

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

The invocation

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a");
```

creates a `String[]` and passes that as the argument to `asList`. This isn't specified clearly by the API documention, but *backed by* seems to indicate that it will return that same array. (Looking at the implementation, it returns a clone.) Since it is a `String[]`, there is no error when casting and assigning it to a variable of that type.

---

In both cases, the appropriate solution is to use the overloaded [`List#toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-).

---

For fun, run the following and check the type of array that is returned.

```
List<String> list1 = (List) Arrays.<Object> asList("a");
System.out.println(list1.toArray().getClass());
```

Don't make assumptions. Always rely on the API documentation. If it isn't clear, try to find a better solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation . I checked the implementation asList(T ...) in Arrays.java , it keeps an array of type T , while in case of ArrayList case Object [] is used .

Answer (score 5):

The different calls to `toArray` are returning arrays with different component types. You can see this by running the following code:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("a");
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a");
    System.out.println(list.toArray().getClass());
    System.out.println(list1.toArray().getClass());
```

On any version of Java 8 or earlier, the result is

```
    class [Ljava.lang.Object;
    class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

Basically this output means `Object[]` and `String[]` respectively.

However, this is a bug. See [JDK-6260652](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6260652). Although it's not stated very clearly, `Collection.toArray()` **must** return an `Object[]` and not an array of some subtype of `Object`. There are a couple reasons for this.

First is that `Collection.toArray()` was introduced in JDK 1.2, long before generics were added to the language. There was no possibility of any collection implementation returning anything other than `Object[]`, so for compatibility, all collections' `toArray()` implementations must return `Object[]`.

The second reason is that a rather offhand comment in the specification for `toArray(T[])` says:

> Note that toArray(new Object[0]) is identical in function to toArray().

which again requires `toArray()` to return `Object[]` and not an array of some other type.

This bug has been fixed in JDK 9. Running the code snippet above on a recent JDK 9 build gives the following output:

```
    class [Ljava.lang.Object;
    class [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

The fact that `Arrays.asList("a")` uses a `String[]` for internal storage is an implementation detail. The bug where `toArray()` returned something other than `Object[]` is this implementation detail leaking out. (In fact, the array is created by the varargs machinery, using the method's type parameter as the array component type. `Arrays.asList()` just wraps the array it's given.)

As others have said, if you want to control the component type of the returned array, use the other overload `toArray(T[])`:

```
    String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
    String[] array1 = list1.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Funny that it's `toArray(T[])` that specifies this critical detail. Will the documentation of `toArray()` also be amended?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah, it probably should be. I just filed [JDK-8160406](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8160406).

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
str = (String[]) list.toArray();
```

In this case your list invoke method toArray() of ArrayList class. Which looks like below, it returns Object []:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
}
```

And elementData declare:

```
transient Object[] elementData;
```

And constructor method:

```
public ArrayList() {
    this.elementData = DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

And DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA:

```
private static final Object[] DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};
```

There for, elementData is totaly Object [] and can't be casted to any type, String etc...

With Arrays.asList(T...), it returns java.util.Arrays$ArrayList class. And   java.util.Arrays$ArrayList also has toArray() method. That subtle toArray() method makes some confuse :). Here is its implementation:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    return a.clone();
}
```

And finally a field declare:

```
private final E[] a;
```

java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.toArray() able to return Object [] and actually E []. Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that `Arrays.asList(..)` does not return a `java.util.ArrayList`, but instead it returns a `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`. So the `.toArray()` methods vary slightly.

If you want the first case to return a String[], you can change the call to

```
str = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```